# Moon phase web service

Tags: web-services

I am looking for a web service that returns the current moon phase as some kind of string, like "Waxing 88%" or a similar string that I can store later in a database.  This is for a mobile app, so would rather not use some of the suggested algorithms to calculate it.

Short of finding this, what is your opinion of calculating this in JavaScript on a device?  Will this be too resource intensive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on an article I found describing moon phase calculation, I can tell you already that sending a network request over the internet, waiting for and then parsing a response, and finally dealing with the calculations is far more resource intensive then simply performing arithmetic on the device. It will almost certainly use less computing power, less battery power, and less network bandwidth.

You can find a simplified calculation method here:

http://www.voidware.com/moon_phase.htm

This project uses JavaScript to both calculate and display moon-phase information, and may be more relevant to you:

https://github.com/tingletech/moon-phase

Comment: Looking at it that way, I'm sure you are right.  I'll calculate it on the device.
Thanks-
Matt

Comment: saddly, its not very accurate